# Which items sold by Stew will net a profit when resold to Jani? And what determines when will Stew change the item he is currenty selling?

Tags: rage

[Stew](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Stew) is an NPC that sells items cheaply. However, he only sells one item at a time.

Which items sold by Stew, will net a profit when resold to [Jani](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Jani) (a merchant buying and selling at normal prices) (and assuming the player character is wearing the [Wastelander](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Wastelander) or [Crimson Elite](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Crimson_Elite) armor, which both give a 5% discount on all cash purchases)?

Stew regularly changes the item he is currenty selling. I also would like to know: What determines when will Stew change the item he is currently selling?

[image: Stew]

The [RAGE wiki](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Stew) already lists some of the items sold by Stew that will net a profit when resold to Jani, but I'd like to know about the rest as Stew regularly changes the items he is selling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer to the first part of my question:

Item — Buying Price from Stew — Selling Price to Jani — Profit
*(prices are with the [Wastelander](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Wastelander) or [Crimson Elite](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Crimson_Elite) armor, which both give a 5% discount on all cash purchases)*

- Authority MG Rounds — $20 — $26 — $6
- Bandage — $10 — $12 — $2
- EMP Grenade — 3 pcs. for $30 — $10 — (no profit)
- HE Grenades — 5 pcs. for $14 — $4 — $6 per 5 pcs.
- Viper Rockets — $66 — $75 — $9

Some of the items listed here are from the ['Stew' article in the RAGE wikia](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Stew). The rest are from gameplay experience.

Feel free to suggest an edit to this answer to add more items, or comment if you reckon it should be a [Community wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki).